# Resizing a link/div with :hover selector for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, resize, hover, width

I'm trying to optimize the following site for mobile devices:
http://whitehallrow.com/

The blue ribbon links function by using a CSS hover selector to change the image when hovered over:

```css
.ribbonlinkA{
    background-image:url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hr_slide_off.png");
    display:block;
    height:86px;
    width:512px;
}
.ribbonlinkA:hover{
    background-image:url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hr_slide_on.png");
    display:block;
    height:86px;
    width:512px;
}
```

I've been using width:100% for the images on the page, which resizes them well on my Blackberry. However, I can't get the ribbon links to resize at all; they simply overflow off the right side of the page, even with width:100%.

How can I get them to resize appropriately?

Comment: Keep in mind that touch devices don't have much of a concept of :hover states

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the `background-size` property (which isn't supported by all browsers) to get CSS backgrounds to scale.  You might be better off using `<img>` elements, toggled with javascript, for larger images (>320px) like you're using.