# menu :hover on IPAD

Tags: jquery

I'm using the same menu design for iPad landscape that I'm using for Desktop, after that it turns to a mobile menu that has a link 'Menu' handle that toggles the menu open.

My problem is that when using an iPad I click on About and it shows the sub menu for a split second then goes off to the page, I need to make the sub menu show until the the user chooses a link with a double tap or something.

I'm using the following CSS to display the children when hovered:

```
#nav li:hover > ul {display:block;}
```

Comment: need more html + css + jquery .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does css hover work on mobile devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices) - very easily found and should already have been suggested when you asked this duplicate

Comment: I simply want on hover on menu items it should show its related submenus for IPAD View because I am using same menu for desktop view and ipad view. Please share the fiddle for reference.