# CSS :hover on mobile or other device as toggle

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am doing a simple `:hover` slide-in cover as shown in picture, it's supposed to slide in a "favorite article" control, which user can then click to favorite this item.

While it work well on desktop with mouse hover and click, I am not sure if it can be used as an effective control on mobile or other device (ie. click to toggle, then click again to favorite item) .

If I understand correctly, at least on iOS (Safari) and Android (Chrome), the default browser behaviour is to emulate touch as both `hover` and `click`. But is it a **standard**? eg.

- Will Windows Phone or maybe a Wii U does the same?
- Will `click` be fired about 300ms after `hover`, so there can be ghost click issue?

I can certainly bind a click/touch event on this element, just wondering if css `:hover` is sufficient nowadays.

**To clarify**: I am not asking about `:hover` support, which only make senses in a pointer driven environment. I am asking if devices can and should handle hover-able element as users click/tap (as iOS/Android do)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `:hover` having the same type of support on all devices. Any touch based browser could implement it differently, and iOS handles it quite poorly IMHO. You should use Modernizr to only bind `:hover` events on `.no-touch` devices (so that touch devices don't try to trigger their own `:hover` state), then bind your touch events separately on `.touch` devices if you wish to trigger hover states on tap for certain elements.

Comment: Have you considered using `feature detection` when something does (or does not) support touch or hover? Along the lines of `"ontouchstart" in document.documentElement

Comment: @RonniSkansing feature detect is very do-able, and probably the standard routine nowadays. But I am curious if we have established any common behaviour for `:hover` handling on non-pointer device in the past 2-3 years.

Comment: @bitinn not all devices support hover. We have established common ways to make gracefull fallbacks for these and other quirks. Use modernizr or as mentioned add a class to a hover element is there is no touch events..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear and I cannot understand whether you're asking "Can I use `:hover` across all the devices?" or "Will `:hover` behave the same across all the devices?" or "Is `:hover` a standard element on the web?"

Also it greatly depends of your concept of "all devices", if you have in mind the currently most used devices or you are taking in account also the less-known and used devices.

I will quote you the following, but I am pretty sure you have already read that:

> Interactive user agents sometimes change the rendering in response to
>   user actions. CSS provides three pseudo-classes for common cases:
>
> The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element
>   (with some **pointing device**), but does not activate it. For example, a
>   visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse
>   pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element. **User agents not
>   supporting interactive media do not have to support this pseudo-class.
>   Some conforming user agents supporting interactive media may not be
>   able to support** this pseudo-class (e.g., **a pen device**). The :active
>   pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user.
>   For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and
>   releases it.
>
> CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how
>   the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements
>   react to user events or not, **and different devices and UAs may have
>   different ways of pointing to, or activating elements**.
>
> *5.11.3 The dynamic pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes*

As you can see on the W3C specification it claims that the `:hover` pseudo-class is not required to a non-interactive media user agents as well as **some** interactive media user agents.
Therefore is safe to assume `:hover` is not always supported.

To dig deep on the matter, take a read at the following specification for Safari Mobile:

> Additionally, Safari on iOS users interact with your web content
>   directly with their fingers, rather than using a mouse. **This creates
>   new opportunities for touch-enabled interfaces, but does not work well
>   with hover states**. For example, **a mouse pointer can hover over a
>   webpage element and trigger an event; a finger on a Multi-Touch screen
>   cannot**. For this reason, **mouse events are emulated in Safari on iOS**.
>   As a result, **elements that rely only on mousemove, mouseover, mouseout
>   or the CSS pseudo-class :hover may not always behave as expected on a
>   touch-screen device such as iPad or iPhone**.
>
> You can handle touches directly or even detect advanced gestures in
>   Safari on iOS, using the DOM Touch events touchstart, touchmove,
>   touchend, and touchcancel. **Unlike mouse events which are emulated**, DOM
>   Touch events are specifically designed to work with touch interfaces,
>   so their behavior is reliable and expected.
>
> *5. Prepare for a touch interface
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html*

Apple clearly states here that they tend to emulate the pointer with the touch gestures, however they clearly suggest to avoid using the `:hover` pseudo-class as won't behave the same on their touch device.

We could dig deeper and fetch every documentation for each user-agent existing on earth but the previous two are enough to assume the following:

- Non interactive devices do not have to support `:hover`
- Interactive devices can support the pseudo-class (but it's not mandatory and they can ignore it, for example screen-readers or braille screens)
- Apple touch devices in absence of a pointer emulates `:hover`
- It is safe to assume current touch devices also emulates `:hover`
- It is safe to assume any other browser/device don't necessarily have to support `:hover` depending on their interface.
- Very likely the recent browsers will all support `:hover` because is a visual aid for the user.

So to answer to all the question(s) I have assumed above:

> "Is `:hover` a standard element on the web?"

Hover is a standard W3C in fact it claims it **must** be triggered by a pointer event, **but** isn't required for some interfaces.

> "Can I use `:hover` across all the devices?"

Yes you **probably** can. The devices which won't support :hover very likely are devices/users that probably aren't your main target. Better ask yourself "Who will be the end-user of my product?" if they are only mobile users or only blind people or only people who like to browse using the Nintendo DS then don't use `:hover` events, otherwise do.

> "Will `:hover` behave the same across all the devices?"

No, as Apple stated on their devices will not behave the same as a desktop would, and that probably reflects the same behaviour on all devices without a pointer.

If you plan to have an user action via a hover state don't do it. This is generally bad practice and it should avoided in any case, including desktop devices. Hover is not an call to action, click is. Hover should not be treated as a "toggle" but more like a visual helper for the user making him/her understand that element, if clicked, triggers an action.

If I understood your application then hover isn't reliable and in your specific case you should rethink on how it should work.
Use a more reliable method (and expected from your user)

Comment: `CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements react to user events or not, and different devices and UAs may have different ways of pointing to, or activating elements.` - so CSS2 spec does state implementation is not required explicitly, now the question becomes if we are seeing any consensus between device makers (or maybe update through newer CSS spec)?

Comment: Either way, I believe we have gone deep enough into this rabbit hole, so points to you sir!

Comment: I take a wild guess there. The concept of hover state obviously came up way long before CSS even existed (think about game menus), desktop browsers have adapted for the same thing later and it's still one of the most used features inside a CSS. At the end of the day your finger is actually a pointer I just think it makes sense to support a feature which has been used everywhere in the past and will be certainly used in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Hovering your cursor over a webpage element is a common action when browsing with a mouse and keyboard, but there is no equivalent when it comes to touch-based browsing. This topic demonstrates how to use the `aria-haspopup` Document Object Model (DOM) property to simulate hover on touch-enabled devices with Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8.

This behavior is not applicable to Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 (which does not support hover simulation with aria-haspopup) or Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 (which has built-in touch hover support).

In touch scenarios, hover is applied to an element while it is being touched. However, tapping an element can also activate an element, such as navigating a link. Effectively, a tap is both hover and activation in one action. This makes interactive content hidden behind hover inaccessible for touch users. The interaction model is completely different, and there is no touch analog to hovering the cursor over a page element.

> The best practice is to not use hover to hide content that a user can
>   interact with. Instead, consider using the onclick event to toggle the
>   visibility.

Comment: "Effectively, a tap is both hover and activation in one action. This makes interactive content hidden behind hover inaccessible for touch users." - this is the part i am not sure about: both iOS and Android are able to tap to reveal `:hover` element, then tap (click) again to activate the control - so this works ok for those 2 devices.

Comment: I mean when you have both a :hover style and a onclick event on, say, a submit button in the :hover area, users end up spending the better part of a second trying to invoke the “click” on the button (300ms for the hover tap, 300ms for the click tap).

Comment: true, especially for iOS as the 300ms isn't removed automatically for `width=device-width` page. But my example works because we have a slide-in css transform effect, that gives user good perceived performance.

Comment: Great :) i missed the bounty ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that part of this question hasn't yet been answered, namely what is the actual behaviour of Windows phones in relation to 'hover'. To clarify:

Consider a web page written for desktop/mouse use in which there is css markup so that 'hover' changes a style applied to an object. If one views that page on iPhone or Android and taps on the object the style change occurs. (i.e. it is behaving as if the object had an onClick() event handler to change the style). Does the same thing happen on a Windows Phone?

I can answer that question, at least for the Nokia Lumia 630 running Win 8.1:

No. As you press down with your finger in the initial part of a tap the style change does occur, but when you release your finger at the end of the tap the style reverts to the original. (This is arguably a more valid interpretation of 'hover' for touch, although whether it is of any practical use is another matter.)

I would add that the iPhone/Safari interpretation of hover also has an 'off' state. This is triggered when you tap on another object.

To show this and allow testing on different devices/browsers I have set up a demo page at [www.davidleader.net/mobiledemo.html](http://www.davidleader.net/mobiledemo.html). This implements onClick(), onMouseover() and :hover to change the opacity of an image, revealing a different one underneath. (It therefore depends on support for opacity, but this has been around for a while.) There is also a 'dumb graphic' to click on to demonstrate the end of hover on the iPhone.

To summarize, as well as there being no *de jure* standards for interpretation of hover on mobile devices there are no *de facto* ones either. Therefore if you are targetting mobiles, avoid 'hover'.

Answer (score 1):

Theres none at the moment that has a good support for :hover state in mobile

[See related question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices/)

I havent use Modernzr.js for mobile , but it says it can detect if the browser supports touch events , so basically it adds ".touch" class in the html tag if the user uses mobile device.

so you'll use it like this, for e.g

```
.touch a:active{ /*css code here */ }
```

hopefully this would help somehow

Comment: I am not asking about `:hover` support, which only make senses in a pointer driven environment. I am asking if devices handle hover-able element as users click/tap (iOS/Android do)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to mobile phones, I doubt there is any standard.  Yes it is very common for a touch device to apply a hover state while is is being touched, but you can never tell if a user could be using any number of browsers that may interpret a hover state differently.

I would say your best bet would be to shoot for the lowest common denominator and just assume that every touch device can only respond to touch actions.

The answer to that, of course, is to write media queries and/or javascript to force the browsers to act the way you want it to.

That's just my personal philosophy, for what it is worth.