# How to remove Hover Effect from DIV when mobile device is detected using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have using **redirection-mobile.js** for detecting the mobile device.
The code for the same is as follows:

```
 if (screen.width < 574) {
       var ref = document.referrer;
       var urls = new Array("http://127.0.0.1/eflip","http://127.0.0.1/eflip");
       var n = ref.match(urls[0]);
       var m = ref.match(urls[1]);
       if ((m!==null) || (n!==null)) {
       stop;
       }
       else if (ref=='') {
       var r = confirm("Small Display is Detected.\nClick \"OK\" for MOBILE SITE.");
       if (r==true) {

       }
        else {
        stop ;
       }
       }
       else
       {
       window.location = "http://127.0.0.1/eflip";
       }
      }
```

`if (r==true)` is the condition to detect the mobile device. Now I want to remove all the hover effects. I have tried `$('element').removeClass()`, but its not working.

Every Help and Comment will be highly appreciated. Thanks to all in advance :-)

Comment: On mobile devices, you don't have a `:hover` state, just an `:active` and `:focus` state. So I think it's not necessary to remove them. Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508598/css-hover-on-mobile-or-other-device-as-toggle

Comment: Hi @23tux thanks for your reply, so do you have any idea how to remove the focus and active using javascript?. Because the mousehover effect which I have on desktop view, I don't want it for mobile view. And that mousehover effect is fired when we focus on div in mobile device

Answer (score 1):

you're talking about removing events or css effects?
if css effects, the elegant way to go is via css, instead of removing the css already applied, just set the css :hover inside a media query like so:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
 /*css you want to apply only in desktop */
   a:hover{...}
}
```

Edit

```
min-device-width: 480px) {
 /*css you want to apply only in desktop */
   a:hover{...}
}
```

Comment: Hi @monxas Thanks for your reply. I want it to be done on mobile, when the mobile device is detected.

Comment: I meant moving previous code to "Desktop only" instead to apply it everywhere and then remove it on mobile. can you provide the code you're trying to stop from being executed?

Comment: When a user opens the webpage in mobile this code will be executed var r = confirm("Small Display is Detected.\nClick \"OK\" for MOBILE SITE.");
       if (r==true) {

       }                                                                                                                                if(r==true) Satisfies then I want to disable hover effects

Comment: I mean I want to see the hover effects you want to remove

Comment: Hi @monxas I got you. You are talking about the media query. The media query you posted will disable to hover effect even when I open the browser from desktop and resize it to 480px or less than that. I don't want it. I want it only when Mobile device is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) to detect the type of your browser.

```
if ( ! Modernizr.touch ) {
    // your desktop effect
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :-) but I have already detected the mobile device. Now what i want to do is want to remove all hover effects which I have applied for the desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect viewport using jQuery

**jQuery :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var viewport = jQuery(window).innerWidth();

        if( viewport < 480 )
            {
            // for mobile device
               jQuery('#yourDiv').css({'transform', 'none !important'});
            }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @Faisal Alvi $('#yourDiv').css({what to write here?}); I just tried jQuery('#yourDiv').css({transform: none}); and its not working

Comment: Try this: jQuery('#yourDiv').css('transform', 'none !important'});.
You should read more about transform css here : [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)