# is hover treated as focused on mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile

I've noticed that sometimes if an element has css rules defined for its `:hover` state on mobile browsers they are applied whenever an element has focus. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3, `:hover` is applied when "some pointing device" is placed over the element:

> The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element
>   (with some pointing device), but does not activate it. For example, a
>   visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse
>   pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element. User agents not
>   supporting interactive media do not have to support this pseudo-class.
>   Some conforming user agents supporting interactive media may not be
>   able to support this pseudo-class (e.g., a pen device).
>   <kbd>[W3 src](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)</kbd>

So, no, `:hover` might not, and is not on some, supported on mobile devices.
You should use `:focus` instead.
[Does css hover work on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices)