# CSS iOS - Why does :hover persist through states

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, react-router, hover

Please run the demo on an iOS device.

I have two pages with similar elements (that have `:hover` states) and clicking on any element in the first page takes you to the second page.

Problems:

- `:hover` persists between pages
- location of `:hover` remains identical (try tapping different links)

This happens until you interact with the page again.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ios-persisting-hover-state-se3m1

Has anyone experienced this before? What solutions do I have to fix it? Would rather not have to add a `no-touch` type class everywhere where I do hover states in my CSS if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does css hover work on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your question: 
https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/